# wm.context_toggle_enum(Context Toggle Values) shortcut setting is not working in Blendre 3.6?

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut

I googled to see if I can toggle menu items with shortcuts and they explains wm.context_toggle_enum(Context Toggle Values)can do that, but in Blender 3.6 this shortcut setting doesn't work. Is there anyway to do same thing in Blneder 3.6? I need to toggle many things like Transform Operations, Transform Pivot Point, Viewport Shading, Snap Elements ,and so on.

Comment: Have you seen this in the Blender Python API? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle_enum

Comment: I saw it. I tried some combinations sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. For example wm.context_toggle_enum context attribute= 
 tool_settings.transform_pivot_point value = CURSOR value = INDIVIDUAL_ORIGINS it works  but this won't work. I don't know why. wm.context_toggle_enum context attribute = 
 tool_settings.snap_elements  value = VERTEX value = EDGE

Comment: FWIW: I wonder if what you just added to your question wouldn't be better posted as an answer to it? It would show more clearly that you found a solution to your problem.

Comment: choosing my post as an answer to my question? If it is ok I will.

Comment: See this link specifically about answering your own question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer Just a suggestion, IMHO it might be clearer if you edited your question to cut out the part beginning with "I found out the reason..." and everything following, including the code snippets and paste all that into an answer. Also, if you have the time and haven't seen it before, you might take a look around the Help Center: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: ok thanx. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason why only snap_elements toggle_enum can't work as keymap in Blender 3.6. When I try this

```
import bpy
print(bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_elements)
print(bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point)
```

this gives me something like

```
{'EDGE'}
BOUNDING_BOX_CENTER
```

tool_settings.transform_pivot_point can toggle transform_pivot_point using wm.context_toggle_enum with values like BOUNDING_BOX_CENTER with CURSOR combination and this can be used as keymap shortcut but tool_settings.snap_elements can't because it needs {''}. Simply values with EDGE and VERTEX won't work anymore. It used to work but Blender developer changed snap_elements enum setting.

I am gonna use this as a custom operator and assign keyboard shortcut instead. I just need to toggle snap elements. I always need to toggle between vertex and edge.

```
import bpy
current_snap_element = bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_elements
if current_snap_element == {'VERTEX'}:
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_elements = {'EDGE'}
elif current_snap_element == {'EDGE'}:
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_elements = {'VERTEX'}
else:
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.snap_elements = {'VERTEX'}
```

I thought wm.context_toggle_enum can't be used as keymap anymore but
other enum things may work as before. At least tool_settings.snap_elements can't be used as shortcut in Blender 3.6 anymore.